# Remove library from page based on node field value

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks, theming

We have a content type, `Basic Page`, where we may want to include 3rd party CSS such as `Bootstrap`. However, this 3rd party CSS may conflict with our custom theme, `mytheme`. On the `Basic Page`, we added a custom field of type Boolean, `field_include_css`, that a content editor can set to true if they want to use the `Bootstrap` CSS instead of `mytheme`.

**How would we remove all the libraries added to the page that come from `mytheme`?**

Here is what we tried, but did not work.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node']'
  // Basic page's machine name is page.
  if(is_object($node) && $node->getType() == 'page' && $node->field_include_css->value == '1') {
    unset($variables['page']['#attached']['library']);

    // above line didn't work so we also tried these, but they failed too.
    $variables['page']['#attached']['library'] = '';
    $variables['#attached']['library'] = '';
    unset($variables['#attached']['library']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal has dedicated theme hook, [`hook_page_attachments_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.6.x), for this scenario. Your theme can hook into it, check the rendered route (for your node type), and take action on the `$page['#attached']['library']` render array accordingly:

```
function MYTHEME_page_attachments_alter(array &$page) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if (!is_null($node) && $node->getType() == 'page') {
    //@TODO: remove the appropriate library items from $page['#attached']['library']
  }
}
```

Comment: using `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')` got me the node i needed and then i was able to do the validation similar to your `if` statement.

Comment: Please be aware that `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')` doesn't always return an object. If it is not an object you'll have to load the node first, before calling methods on it.